# Delete a row based on a full date yyyy-mm-dd using delete and where

Tags: postgresql

How to delete a row in Postgresql

Comment: Try the manual, because the question is not very clear to me. DELETE will never UPDATE a record, unless you do something with RULES. For now, check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-delete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you generated the &A2& with excel. If that is the case you want excel to do the formatting:

```
=TEXT(A2;"YYYY-MM-DD") .
```

If not you probably need to cast the date explicitly to a date

Comment: HI I use excel yes. is there is any easier way to perform the task plz?

Comment: Well, that all depends on what data is in excel and what data is on your database. If the criteria on which to delete the dates is actually in your DB you should be able to do smt like: ` DELETE from <table> WHERE date in (select date from table where >some criterium>)`